# Excel-DNA, issue with firing Ribbon's onAction code. F#

Tags: f#, ribbon, excel-dna

I am on Excel 2010 and trying to run the [Excel-DNA/Samples code](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/blob/master/FSharpRibbon/MyRibbon.fs) for ribbon customization in F#.

```
<tab id='CustomTab' label='My F# Tab'>
   <group id='SampleGroup' label='My Sample Group'>
        <button id='Button1' label='Run a macro' onAction='RunTagMacro' tag='showMessage' />    <!-- works fine -->
        <button id='Button3' label='Dump the Excel Version to cell A1' onAction='OnDumpData'/>  <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
```

The Button1's action works, and placing a break-point on line 14 works as expected.

However Button3's action, OnDumpData, does not. I can see that the code is never called since a break-point placed on line 45 is never hit.

```
member this.OnDumpData (control:IRibbonControl) =
    let app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application :?> Application  // line 45. Breakpoint here is never reached.
    let cellA1 = app.Range("A1")
```

I first thought that it might be a versioning issue and I tried to replace the cutomUI line (#26) `.../office/2006/01...`  with `.../office/2009/07...` but the problem persisted.

What did I miss (a setting or something...)? How can I get the Button3 to fire the OnDumpData code properly?

EDIT1:
As suggested in the sample files, I switched-on the *Excel Option "Show add-in user interface errors" option (under the Advanced tab under General)*. The error message I got while pressing on Button3 is :

```
An exception occurred while calling function "OnDumpDate". Exception message is :
Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

... And then I noticed that when I close the debug Excel sheet, I get this message in VS's output window `ExcelDna.Integration Warning: 1 : Assembly OFFICE could not be loaded from resources.`. It's probably related but I am not completely sure where to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a reference to the Office.dll assembly in your project. This is only of the COM-related PIA assemblies (like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel).

Either add directly to your project, or install the NuGet package called "ExcelDna.Interop" which includes this library and should add a reference too.

Comment: Thanks Govert. I installed the NuGet package ExcelDna.Interop and it works like a charm now.